# How to return a variable after assigning it a value in an If/Else statement in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return-value

I am having trouble returning a variable after I have assigned it a value in a an if else statement.

I have inserted the method in which I am attempting to do this below.
I need to return the variable "absolutepday" and its value, in the if else statements, for use in a later method.

[Context] This code segment is supposed to input the present date and output the absolute day of the year that corresponds with that date. (Ex. 1/15 is the 15th absolute day of the year)

Any and all help is appreciated!

```
public static void todaysdate()
{
    int absolutepday = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter today's date:");

    System.out.print("What is the month (1-12)? ");
    int pmonth = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What is the day   (1-31)? ");
    int pday = input.nextInt();      

    if (pmonth == 1)
        absolutepday = pday;
    else if (pmonth == 2)
        absolutepday = 31 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 3)
        absolutepday = 59 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 4)
        absolutepday = 90 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 5)
        absolutepday = 120 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 6)
        absolutepday = 151 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 7)
        absolutepday = 181 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 8)
        absolutepday = 212 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 9)
        absolutepday = 243 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 10)
        absolutepday = 273 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 11)
        absolutepday = 304 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 12)
        absolutepday = 334 + pday;

    System.out.println(pmonth + "/" + pday + " is day #" + absolutepday + " of 365");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Please learn about arrays.  When you have a long sequence where you're comparing a value to one possibility, then to another possibility, then to another, etc., that's a sign that you need to make your code a lot shorter by using an array or map.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the return type of the function from void to int.

```
public static int todaysdate()

{
    int absolutepday = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter today's date:");

    System.out.print("What is the month (1-12)? ");
    int pmonth= input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What is the day   (1-31)? ");
    int pday= input.nextInt();      

    if (pmonth == 1)
    absolutepday = pday;
    else if (pmonth == 2)
    absolutepday = 31 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 3)
    absolutepday = 59 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 4)
    absolutepday = 90 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 5)
    absolutepday = 120 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 6)
    absolutepday = 151 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 7)
    absolutepday = 181 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 8)
    absolutepday = 212 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 9)
    absolutepday = 243 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 10)
    absolutepday = 273 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 11)
    absolutepday = 304 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 12)
    absolutepday = 334 + pday;
    System.out.println(pmonth + "/" + pday + " is day #" + absolutepday + " of 365");
    System.out.println();
    return absolutepday;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the if else does not placed inside a method, which is a basic concept when writing Java class:

Try the following suggestion:

```
public class MainApp {

public static void todaysdate(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter today's date:");

    System.out.print("What is the month (1-12)? ");
    int pmonth = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What is the day   (1-31)? ");
    int pday = input.nextInt();

    Integer absolutePDay = getAbsolutePDay(pmonth, pday);

    }

public static int getAbsolutePDay(Integer pmonth, Integer pday) {

    int absolutepday = 0;
    if (pmonth == 1)
        absolutepday = pday;
    else if (pmonth == 2)
        absolutepday = 31 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 3)
        absolutepday = 59 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 4)
        absolutepday = 90 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 5)
        absolutepday = 120 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 6)
        absolutepday = 151 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 7)
        absolutepday = 181 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 8)
        absolutepday = 212 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 9)
        absolutepday = 243 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 10)
        absolutepday = 273 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 11)
        absolutepday = 304 + pday;
    else if (pmonth == 12)
        absolutepday = 334 + pday;

    System.out.println(pmonth + "/" + pday + " is day #" + absolutepday + " of 365");
    System.out.println();
    return absolutepday;
}

}
```

Comment: You cannot nest a method inside another method.

Comment: OK, so you fixed one problem.  But now you're calling the method to return a value, but you're throwing the return value away because you're not using it.

Comment: You can use it if you wish for other uses :-) here there is no special use for that.

Comment: OK, but now you're not answering the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

For a method to return something, it must have a return type and what it actually returns.

import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter today's date:");

System.out.print("What is the month (1-12)? ");
int pmonth = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("What is the day   (1-31)? ");
int pday = input.nextInt();

getAbsolutePDay(pmonth, pday);

}

public static int getAbsolutePDay(int pmonth, int pday) {

int absolutepday = 0;
if (pmonth == 1)
    absolutepday = pday;
else if (pmonth == 2)
    absolutepday = 31 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 3)
    absolutepday = 59 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 4)
    absolutepday = 90 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 5)
    absolutepday = 120 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 6)
    absolutepday = 151 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 7)
    absolutepday = 181 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 8)
    absolutepday = 212 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 9)
    absolutepday = 243 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 10)
    absolutepday = 273 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 11)
    absolutepday = 304 + pday;
else if (pmonth == 12)
    absolutepday = 334 + pday;

System.out.println(pmonth + "/" + pday + " is day #" + absolutepday + " of 365");
System.out.println();
return absolutepday;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of your method from void to int, then at the end of your method call return with the variable you want to return with.

```
public static int todaysdate() { 
    int absolutepday = 0; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter today's date:"); 
    System.out.print("What is the month (1-12)? "); 
    int pmonth= input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is the day (1-31)? "); 
    int pday= input.nextInt(); 
    if (pmonth == 1) 
        absolutepday = pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 2) 
        absolutepday = 31 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 3) 
        absolutepday = 59 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 4) 
        absolutepday = 90 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 5) 
        absolutepday = 120 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 6) 
        absolutepday = 151 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 7) 
        absolutepday = 181 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 8) 
        absolutepday = 212 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 9) 
        absolutepday = 243 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 10) 
        absolutepday = 273 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 11) 
        absolutepday = 304 + pday; 
    else if (pmonth == 12) 
        absolutepday = 334 + pday;
    System.out.println(pmonth + "/" + pday + " is day #" + absolutepday + " of 365"); 
    System.out.println(); 
    return absolutepday;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the actual problem (`return absolutepday`) it is often useful to use libraries for that kind of problems (if it is not some assignment which you have to solve own your own).

Apparently, you want to calculate the day of a year. This can be done in Java using the Date API. It also takes leap years into account, so you don't have to worry about them.

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2000,pmonth,pday);
int dayOfYear = d.getDayOfYear();
```